# Google Chrome Crashes Memory leak or Any rendering issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-leaks, webkit, v8

We have a SPA running on Chrome Browser. It is Crashing *intermittently* after using the application for some time. I am getting the Aw Snap error Page.

[image]

I enabled the logs in the Chrome and found out following information in the log files. Additionally, Google Chrome doesn't generate a Dump file even after enabling the Dump file setting in Chrome.

**Error Message in Chrome Logs**

```
[0226/100630:INFO:SkScalerContext.cpp(170)] --- no context for glyph 6f
[0226/100630:INFO:SkScalerContext.cpp(170)] --- no context for glyph b3
[0226/100630:INFO:SkScalerContext.cpp(170)] --- no context for glyph 11b
[0226/100630:INFO:SkScalerContext.cpp(170)] --- no context for glyph bf
[0226/100630:INFO:SkScalerContext.cpp(170)] --- no context for glyph 48
[0226/100630:INFO:SkScalerContext.cpp(170)] --- no context for glyph 46
[0226/100630:INFO:SkScalerContext.cpp(170)] --- no context for glyph 23
[0226/100630:INFO:SkCanvas.cpp(747)] Unable to create device for layer.
[0226/100630:INFO:SkCanvas.cpp(747)] Unable to create device for layer.
[0226/100630:INFO:SkCanvas.cpp(747)] Unable to create device for layer.
```

Can anyone give some pointers as to what the error message **"Unable to create device for layer."** and **"no context for glyph"** means and what can be the possible reasons for this error message?

Since the crash happens after using the application for some time, i am suspecting a memory leak. Is it possible that the error is happening because of memory leak?

**EDIT 1:**

There seems to be memory leak as the Javascript Memory is increasing. Also, the Heap Allocation shows the increasing memory which is not getting Cleared. However, the SPA itself is little complex and having a lot of Objects and i will analyze what Objects are Preventing other Objects from GC.

Additionally, the Chrome creates a `0Kb` dump file in the CrashReports folder.

Moreover, i took a process dump and analyzed using **windbg**. Following is the output from !analyze-v command. I am analyzing the memory dumps and from the windbg it seems that an access violation exception is raised and it seems that no memory is available for allocating the Bitmap. Does this dump information point to any other useful information as well?

```
FAULTING_IP: 
chrome_1490000!skia::CrashForBitmapAllocationFailure+70 [c:\b\build\slave\chrome-official\build\src\skia\ext\platform_canvas_win.cc @ 46]
01956d67 mov     dword ptr ds:[3],0

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 01956d67 (chrome_1490000!skia::CrashForBitmapAllocationFailure+0x00000070)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 00000001
   Parameter[1]: 00000003
Attempt to write to address 00000003

PROCESS_NAME:  chrome.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  00000001

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  00000003

WRITE_ADDRESS:  00000003 

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
chrome_1490000!skia::CrashForBitmapAllocationFailure+70 [c:\b\build\slave\chrome-official\build\src\skia\ext\platform_canvas_win.cc @ 46]
01956d67 mov     dword ptr ds:[3],0

MOD_LIST: <ANALYSIS/>

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

FAULTING_THREAD:  00002fac

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_NULL_CLASS_PTR_DEREFERENCE_INVALID_POINTER_WRITE

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  NULL_CLASS_PTR_DEREFERENCE

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  NULL_CLASS_PTR_DEREFERENCE

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 014ef4ed to 01956d67

STACK_TEXT:  
003deb9c 014ef4ed 000004cc 000000d6 00000057 chrome_1490000!skia::CrashForBitmapAllocationFailure+0x70 [c:\b\build\slave\chrome-official\build\src\skia\ext\platform_canvas_win.cc @ 46]
003debc0 0160893b 000004cc 000000d6 00000001 chrome_1490000!skia::PlatformCanvas::initialize+0x97 [c:\b\build\slave\chrome-official\build\src\skia\ext\platform_canvas_win.cc @ 107]
003debe4 016086ef 000004cc 000000d6 003ded54 chrome_1490000!TransportDIB::GetPlatformCanvas+0x3f [c:\b\build\slave\chrome-official\build\src\ui\gfx\surface\transport_dib_win.cc @ 74]
003dec04 0160696b 035f4774 000000d6 003dedd8 chrome_1490000!RenderProcessImpl::GetDrawingCanvas+0x4d [c:\b\build\slave\chrome-official\build\src\content\renderer\render_process_impl.cc @ 169]
003ded80 01606488 035f4700 017ec98a 003def0c chrome_1490000!RenderWidget::DoDeferredUpdate+0x49b [c:\b\build\slave\chrome-official\build\src\content\renderer\render_widget.cc @ 843]
003ded88 017ec98a 003def0c 035f4700 03606ab8 chrome_1490000!RenderWidget::DoDeferredUpdateAndSendInputAck+0x8 [c:\b\build\slave\chrome-official\build\src\content\renderer\render_widget.cc @ 731]
003dedb4 017ec725 015d826f 1d660a04 035f4700 chrome_1490000!RenderWidget::OnUpdateRectAck+0xe1 [c:\b\build\slave\chrome-official\build\src\content\renderer\render_widget.cc @ 383]
003dedb8 015d826f 1d660a04 035f4700 035f4700 chrome_1490000!IPC::Message::Dispatch<RenderWidget,RenderWidget>+0x1a [c:\b\build\slave\chrome-official\build\src\ipc\ipc_message.h @ 138]
003def0c 015c10c8 1d660a04 1d660a04 1d660a04 chrome_1490000!RenderWidget::OnMessageReceived+0xb0 [c:\b\build\slave\chrome-official\build\src\content\renderer\render_widget.cc @ 201]
003df420 0154d34f 1d660a04 03613d84 0154d329 chrome_1490000!RenderViewImpl::OnMessageReceived+0x1381 [c:\b\build\slave\chrome-official\build\src\content\renderer\render_view_impl.cc @ 764]
003df42c 0154d329 1d660a04 0150aed5 1d660a04 chrome_1490000!MessageRouter::RouteMessage+0x23 [c:\b\build\slave\chrome-official\build\src\content\common\message_router.cc @ 47]
003df434 0150aed5 1d660a04 003df510 00000000 chrome_1490000!MessageRouter::OnMessageReceived+0x1b [c:\b\build\slave\chrome-official\build\src\content\common\message_router.cc @ 39]
003df490 014c39f0 1d660a04 00000002 014c0c8a chrome_1490000!ChildThread::OnMessageReceived+0x178 [c:\b\build\slave\chrome-official\build\src\content\common\child_thread.cc @ 201]
003df49c 014c0c8a 1d6609f0 00000000 1d6609f4 chrome_1490000!base::internal::Invoker<2,base::internal::BindState<base::internal::RunnableAdapter<void (__thiscall quota::QuotaManagerProxy::*)(GURL const &)>,void __cdecl(quota::QuotaManagerProxy *,GURL const &),void __cdecl(quota::QuotaManagerProxy *,GURL)>,void __cdecl(quota::QuotaManagerProxy *,GURL const &)>::Run+0x16 [c:\b\build\slave\chrome-official\build\src\base\bind_internal.h @ 1254]
003df4e8 014c0962 003df748 003df510 003df748 chrome_1490000!MessageLoop::RunTask+0x21e [c:\b\build\slave\chrome-official\build\src\base\message_loop.cc @ 460]
003df758 01493ffd 0a805c60 00000051 00000004 chrome_1490000!MessageLoop::DoWork+0x2d1 [c:\b\build\slave\chrome-official\build\src\base\message_loop.cc @ 661]
003df860 014a5d87 035f0780 035f0788 035f0788 chrome_1490000!tcmalloc::ThreadCache::Deallocate+0x2c [c:\b\build\slave\chrome-official\build\src\third_party\tcmalloc\chromium\src\thread_cache.h @ 346]
003df930 014a86c6 00000014 0000001f 03613d84 chrome_1490000!std::_Allocate<unsigned short>+0x71 [c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xmemory @ 44]
003df98c 014b03f0 00000000 00000008 00000000 chrome_1490000!std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::compare+0x4b [c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xstring @ 2051]
003df9a8 014b1fe4 003dfa20 003dfab0 00000000 chrome_1490000!std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::compare+0x26 [c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xstring @ 2027]
003df9bc 014a54b4 003dfa78 003dfa20 003dfab0 chrome_1490000!`anonymous namespace'::RunNamedProcessTypeMain+0x42 [c:\b\build\slave\chrome-official\build\src\content\app\content_main.cc @ 264]
003dfa98 014a5244 01360000 003dfb98 003dfab0 chrome_1490000!content::ContentMain+0x224 [c:\b\build\slave\chrome-official\build\src\content\app\content_main.cc @ 457]
003dfacc 01385239 01360000 003dfb98 003dfba0 chrome_1490000!ChromeMain+0x1e [c:\b\build\slave\chrome-official\build\src\chrome\app\chrome_main.cc @ 28]
003dfb44 0138471d 01360000 003dfb98 fffffffe chrome!MainDllLoader::Launch+0xf1 [c:\b\build\slave\chrome-official\build\src\chrome\app\client_util.cc @ 343]
003dfba4 013a33ff 01360000 00000000 005e2fa4 chrome!wWinMain+0x60 [c:\b\build\slave\chrome-official\build\src\chrome\app\chrome_exe_main_win.cc @ 37]
003dfc34 76fb343d 7efde000 003dfc80 777f9832 chrome!__tmainCRTStartup+0x112 [f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crt0.c @ 263]
003dfc40 777f9832 7efde000 77d58cd7 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
003dfc80 777f9805 013a346a 7efde000 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
003dfc98 00000000 013a346a 7efde000 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b


STACK_COMMAND:  ~0s; .ecxr ; kb

FAULTING_SOURCE_CODE:  
No source found for 'c:\b\build\slave\chrome-official\build\src\skia\ext\platform_canvas_win.cc'


SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

SYMBOL_NAME:  chrome!skia::CrashForBitmapAllocationFailure+70

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: chrome_1490000

IMAGE_NAME:  chrome.dll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4f331615

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  NULL_CLASS_PTR_DEREFERENCE_c0000005_chrome.dll!skia::CrashForBitmapAllocationFailure

BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_FAULT_NULL_CLASS_PTR_DEREFERENCE_INVALID_POINTER_WRITE_chrome!skia::CrashForBitmapAllocationFailure+70

WATSON_STAGEONE_URL:  http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/chrome_exe/18_0_1025_11/4f331682/chrome_dll/18_0_1025_11/4f331615/c0000005/004c6d67.htm?Retriage=1

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

**Note:** This error in not coming in the latest Chrome & Canary Build. We are getting this error on the Older version of Chrome (32 bit).

Answer (score 1):

The messages you see in the log file are probably unrelated and not serious, considering that they say `INFO` at the beginning.

A memory leak could absolutely be what's causing the tab crashes. As a quick test, you can open Chrome's process manager and check if memory consumption of the tab in question grows over time.

Once you have confirmed the suspicion that there is a memory leak, the DevTools are your best friend for figuring out what's going on. Two approaches that are often useful are:

1. Take a heap snapshot, perform some sequence of operations where afterwards memory consumption should be the same as it was before you started (i.e. navigate somewhere and back, or the like), take a second heap snapshot, and use the comparison tool to compare them. Anything that's in the second snapshot but not in the first could point you towards the leak.
2. Use the "allocation timeline" feature. It indicates when objects are allocated, and which of them are still around.

If you believe that the leak is in Chrome rather than your own app, please file a bug at [crbug.com/new](http://crbug.com/new) and include instructions on how to reproduce the problem. If you post the bug number here, I can make sure it gets looked at. A quick test to determine whether the cause is likely your own app or the browser is to run it in another browser and see if you observe the same crash (and/or increase in memory consumption) there.

Comment: Thanks @jmrk; I do see a memory leak using the Heap Allocation Timeline. Additionally, I have provided the dump details, could you please check if it provides additional information..

Comment: It confirms that the reason for the crash is an out-of-memory situation.

Comment: Thanks @jrmk for insights. I have seen that certain time chrome crashes and gives the error message "Chrome ran out of memory.." which seems to suggest directly a memory issue. However, in my scenario i am getting the  "something went wrong message". Shouldn't the error message be the same if the Chrome run's out of memory? Also, does increasing the heap size --max-old-space-size help in memory. We would be ultimately fixing the memory leak issue but is there a option for adding any flag in Chrome as a temporary Fix.

Comment: I'm not sure why the error messages are different; it might depend on which component happens to contain the failing allocation. -- `--max-old-space-size` only affects the JavaScript heap limit, whereas in your dump it looks like the overall process was out of memory. There is no flag that helps against that. A 64-bit build of Chrome might give you more breathing room, assuming your machine has enough memory.